# What is a good gmapping alternative?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS gmapping package appears to be orphaned. It took a long time to get into Medlodic, and is now in the same situation with Noetic.

I am thinking maybe this is **my problem** for still using gmapping in 2020?

So what are some good, maintained, easy to use for beginners, alternatives to gmapping in 2020?

I got started with gmapping using Turtlebot tutorials, and those were easy for me to follow and the package has always served me relatively well.
I've tried Cartographer, but honestly it felt like an uphill battle against something that was never intended to work in ROS.

P.S. If the answer really is, "Cartographer is the best mapping system for ROS in 2020." then just give me the hard truth and I will dedicate my time to sorting out my issues with that instead of Gmapping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357370/what-is-a-good-gmapping-alternative?/) by [ChrisL8](https://answers.ros.org/users/19020/chrisl8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2020-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SLAM Toolbox: https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox is the new default SLAM vendor for ROS2 and there's ROS1 version too.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChrisL8](https://answers.ros.org/users/19020/chrisl8/) on 2020-07-18**:
This looks **very** promising! I am going to try it immediately on my Melodic setup.